# C# Sort Lambda, what to return?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm scoring the web wide and low and I can't find a simple answer to this.

What am I suppose to return on `List<T>.Sort()`? Is is index or the shift (Like Java)

My code:

```
newUsers.Sort((userB, userA) => {

                    // User pos -1 means they have no pos.
                    if (userA.pos == -1 && userB.pos == -1) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    if (userA.pos == -1) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if (userB.pos == -1) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if (userA.pos < userB.pos) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            );
```

Comment: I thought sort always returned an int

Comment: @BugFinder He's asking what the meaning of that integer is.

Comment: Read the documentation for the method.  It will tell you how to use it properly.

Comment: oh, I thought it was fairly obvious from the code, I thought as he was asking what he should be returning.. its not the index no, its the how it compares to the other item

Comment: @servy where? Looking at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx there's nothing that says what the int is suppose to be.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns That's because you're not passing an `IComparer`, you're passing a `Comparison`.  That said, it does actually explain as much on that page, given that `IComparer` uses the same meaning for the value it returns in its comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

- Left value is smaller compared to the right value: **less 0**
- Left value is greater compared to the right value: **greater 0**
- Values are equal: **0**

Example:

```
int x1 = 1;
int x2 = 2;
int res1 = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x1,x2);  //-1 (1<2)
int res2 = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x2, x1); //1  (2>1)
int res3 = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x1, x1); //0  (1=1)
```

Instead of `-1` you can also use any other value `< 0` (or any positive value `> 0` instead of `1`) with the same result - but those three values are commonly used.

And depeding from this value the `Sort()` method arranges the sort order of your list.

Comment: But which direction is this?

Comment: @fubo Then do so as an example, rather than stating an incorrect usage of the method.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns the direction  depens on `-1`, `1` or `0`. That values is used to arrange the sort order.

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN doc of [Comparison Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) is returns an  System.Int32:

```
public delegate int Comparison<in T>(
    T x,
    T y
)
```

> A signed integer that indicates the relative values of x and y, as shown in the following table.

```
Value           | Meaning
--------------------------------------
Less than 0     | x is less than y.
0               | x equals y.
Greater than 0  | x is greater than y.
```

---

In your trivial case, if you're not sure what to do and since you compare only `pos`, you could have used:

```
newUsers.Sort((userA, userB) => {
                userA.pos.CompareTo(userB.pos);
            }
        );
```

Which will do the whole work for you.

Comment: Less than and greater than implies the movement on the list?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns which *movements* are you talking about?